# Command not found with sudo

Tags: permissions, sudo, kali-linux

I am trying to install quiche on my kali v2020 using [this](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/docs/HTTP3.md#quiche-version) guide and on this step I get:

```bsh
$ QUICHE_BSSL_PATH=$PWD/deps/boringssl cargo build --release --features pkg-config-meta,qlog
    Updating crates.io index
error: failed to write /home/kali/quiche/quiche/Cargo.lock

Caused by:
  failed to open: /home/kali/quiche/quiche/Cargo.lock

Caused by:
  Permission denied (os error 13)
```

So I tried with `sudo` but then it says

```bsh
sudo: cargo: command not found
```

I even tried changing folder permission to 777, but still same issue. What is the reason? It's baffling me!

Comment: Why are you not root?

Comment: @kemotep Building something should not require being root. Installing it in the end _might_.  They say they changed the directory permissions, but do not say anything about the _intermediate_ directories (must have `x` permissions).

Comment: I even changed the permission of the file is requires to write into to 777, still it doesn't work

Comment: Seems like a lock file. Can you remove the lock file and try building again? Do not use sudo for building.

Comment: @kusalananda. I understand. I was asking why they are not root on their Kali Linux system. I am sure there are scenarios where you do not want to be root using Kali but I would not use Kali in those scenarios to avoid all the pitfalls common to using Kali.